Proving $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \ge 2(a+b+c)-3$, if $ab+bc+ca=3abc$ and $a,b,c \ge 0$
If $a,b,c\ge 0$, proving $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \ge 2(a+b+c)-3,~~~~~(*)$$
if $ab+bc+ca=3abc.$ I can only show that these statements are consistent.
As
$$abc=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}\ge (abc)^{2/3} \implies abc\ge 1.~~~~(1)$$Next, by AM-GM we have $$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge 1.~~~~(2)$$
Then $(*)$ implies $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \ge 3,$$
which is true by AM-GM again, as
$$\frac{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a}{3} \ge (abc)=1.$$
The question is how to prove it otherwise?

Another first solution:
$$ab+bc+ca = 3abc \iff \frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{c} = 3$$
Applying the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:
$$
3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)=\left(\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{c} \right)(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)\ge (a+b+c)^2\tag{1}
$$
And as
$$(a+b+c)^2-6(a+b+c)+9=(a+b+c-3)^2 \ge0\tag{2}$$
From $(1),(2)$, we deduce:
$$3(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)\ge 6(a+b+c)-9 \iff a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\ge 2(a+b+c)-3$$
Q.E.D
Another second solution:
Applying the AM-GM inequality:
$$a^2b +\frac{1}{b}+a\ge3\sqrt[3]{a^3} = a$$
Make the sum, we deduce:
$$(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a) +\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{c} \right)}_{=3} + (a+b+c) \ge 3(a+b+c) $$
$$\iff a^2b+b^2c+c^2a \ge 2(a+b+c) -3$$
Q.E.D.

Note: For your second solution, you can simplify it to $ a^2b  + \frac{1}{b} \geq 2a$, which is exactly what the problem asks for. (Note that your RHS should be $3a$).
